# MySql PHP stored procedures, transactions and rollbacks

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

I am using Stored procedures to do CRUD operations on `Mysql DB`

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `transaction_sp` ()

BEGIN

   DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
   BEGIN
     -- ERROR
     ROLLBACK;
   END;

   DECLARE exit handler for sqlwarning
   BEGIN
    -- WARNING
    ROLLBACK;
   END;

  START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO table_name (id, name, address) values ('1','Test','xpert.com');
    SET @LID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO table_name3 (id, job, responsibilities) values 
    (@LID,'Sr. Developer','Coding,mentoring etc');
COMMIT;
END
$$
```

Now, i want that if Second INSERT statement fails then second SQL statement shall not execute and first Insert shall be rolled back.

With my above approach 1st transaction is not rolled back. Do i need to set any flags?

How to handle it? Well explained answer will help here.

Comment: What is the engine used for the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my answer below. I believe if you check  `@@ROWCOUNT` or `@@Error` after each insert you can rollback if there is no rows affected. Sorry if the method I used is wrong.

```
DELIMITER $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE `transaction_sp` ()

    BEGIN

       DECLARE @nRowCount1 int,
       @nRowCount2  int

       DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
       BEGIN
         -- ERROR
         ROLLBACK;
       END;

       DECLARE exit handler for sqlwarning
       BEGIN
        -- WARNING
        ROLLBACK;
       END;

      START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO table_name (id, name, address) values ('1','Test','xpert.com');
        SET @LID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        SET @nRowCount1 =   @@ROWCOUNT ;
        INSERT INTO table_name3 (id, job, responsibilities) values 
        (@LID,'Sr. Developer','Coding,mentoring etc');
        SET @nRowCount2 =@@ROWCOUNT
        if(@nRowCount1 <=0 and @nRowCount2<=0)
        begin
            ROLLBACK ;
        end
    COMMIT;
    END
    $$
```